# R Shiny Error: "Object of Type Closer is not Subsettable"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the renderDataTable function for the first time, and I am passing a reactive variable into it like this:

```
x<-reactive ({x[1:3]<-input$num 
    }) 
    output$table <- renderDataTable(x())
```

When I run the app, I am told "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

**What I Know**

I understand that the error is most likely generated because I am passing a function, not a data frame, called x.

**What I Don't Know**

How can I solve this issue? I very much need to pass x() through the renderDataTable. I have tried setting it equal to another variable and passing it that way, but it didn't work.

Can you please give me some advice as to how I can use renderDataTable in this situation?

Comment: I don't think you can have generic names like `table` for `output$table` try a different name.

Comment: what is `x[1:3]<-input$num` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work. Let me know otherwise.

```
myx<-reactive ({
     x[1:3]<-input$num 
     x
}) 
output$table <- renderDataTable(data.frame(x=myx()))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Why do you think my code did not work but yours did?

Comment: The error shows your `x()` is confusing. It should not complain if your reactive function gets the right object. So I specifically return object `x` in the reactive function. Plus, I'm not sure if it matters when you use `x` as the same name with your vector named `x`. Therefore I use `myx` instead of `x`. Hope this helps.